# How to write content of two files to another file using python

Tags: python, file

I have a two files with the following contents:

users.txt

```
Administrator
test_user1
test_user2
test_user3
```

policies.txt

```
[a]
[b]
[c]
[d]
```

I need to copy the contents of these two files to a third one in `xls` format alternately, like the following:

output.xls

```
Administrator
[a]
test_user1
[b]
test_user2
[c]
test_user3
[d]
```

I code this way

```
with open("output.xls", "w") as f3:
    with open("users.txt", "r") as f1:
        with open("policies.txt", "r") as f2:
            for linea1 in f1:
                for linea2 in f2:
                    f3.write(linea1)
                    f3.write(linea2)
```

But the `output.xls` file comes out this way:

```
Administrator
[a]
Administrator
[b]
Administrator
[c]
Administrator
[d]
```

How can I solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like you need `zip`:

```
with open("output.xls", "w") as f3:
    with open("users.txt", "r") as f1:
        with open("policies.txt", "r") as f2:
            for linea1,linea2 in zip(f1,f2):
                f3.write(linea1)
                f3.write(linea2)
```

You definitely need to write two lines together. One from the first file, one from the second.